# What level is the default level equal to, in DispatchQoS?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

The DispatchQoS structure, as does the DispatchQoS.QoSClass enumeration, defines a `default` quality of service.

After looking at the Apple references, I still cannot figure out the level. Even when stopping it in the debugger and printing out the value, it only lists `default`.

Command-clicking on the property in Xcode shows me this:

```
@available(OSX 10.10, iOS 8.0, *)
        case `default`
```

The struct reference doesn't provide anything helpful:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqos

The enumeration reference is similar:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqos/qosclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it! An explanation for `default` in Table 4-2 a document titled 'Energy Efficiency Guide for iOS Apps':

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html

It's unfortunate that the developer docs don't have the same level of in-depth explanations as this document.